# Motor Control Help

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, sensors

Here is my objective:

If the value of `EMGv` is at or above 900, start moving the motors left. The motors should continue to move left for a maximum of one second, provided `EMGv` stays at or above 900. If during this time `EMGv` goes below 900, the motors should move right for one second. Then the motors should stop. At any time after this should `EMGv` go above 900 again, the process should repeat.

In simpler terms, the project is a robotic hand, wired to an EMG circuit. When the EMG signal gets above 900 the hand should close by the motors all turning left for one second and when the signal goes below 900 the hand should open by the motors turning right for one second.

Here is my loop atm when `move(motor #, speed, direction (1 for left, 0 for right))` is the function to move the motors and `stop()` stops all motors

```
void loop(){

  unsigned long starttime; //time limit for hand movement
  int EMGv = analogRead(EMG);
  starttime=millis();
  while(EMGv >= 900){
    if (millis()-starttime < 1000) //limit on 1000ms
    {
    move(0, 255, 1); //motor 1, full speed, left
    move(1, 255, 1); //motor 2, full speed, left
    move(2, 255, 1); //motor 3, full speed, left
    move(3, 255, 1); //motor 4, full speed, left
    move(4, 255, 1); //motor 5, full speed, left  
    } else {
      stop();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can edit this question to incorporate some examples and the specification you wrote for a later question.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you would do well to first write (in English) the *exact* set of rules you want it to follow -- don't worry about the code to begin with - get it clear in your head what you want the code to do.  (If this is already clear to you, then just write it :-) )

Here's what I think you might mean -- although it's not exactly what you wrote.

*If EMG is at or above 900, start moving the motors left.  The motors should continue to move left for a maximum of one second, provided EMG stays at or above 900.  If during this time EMG goes below 900, the motors should move right for one second.  Then the motors should stop.*

Once you have that, turning it into code looks well within your ability, judging by the code you've posted.  Here's my attempt - note that it'll only be correct if I have correctly stated your desired rules.  (And if I've correctly guessed how the `move` API works - I guess it starts the motor moving, that you need to cancel it to stop it moving.  Please say if this is wrong.)

I've used LEFT and RIGHT instead of 1 and *whatever*, for clarity.

```
void loop(){
  // If EMG is at or above 900
  int EMGv = analogRead(EMG);
  if (EMGv >= 900) 
  {
    unsigned long starttime = millis();

    // Start the motors moving left
    move(0, 255, LEFT); //motor 1, full speed, left
    ...and the other motors...

    // Continue for a maximum of one second, and while EMG stays at or above 900
    while ( (millis()-starttime < 1000) && ((EMGv = analogRead(EMG)) >= 900)) {
      // Just wait
      delay(1);
    }

    // If during this time EMG goes below one second...
    if (EMGv < 900) {
      // ...the motors should move right for one second
      move(0, 255, RIGHT); //motor 1, full speed, right
      ...and the other motors...
    }

    // Then the motors should stop.
    move(0, 0, LEFT); //motor 1, stop, left
    ...and the other motors...
  }

// More stuff here, otherwise it will immediately go round the loop again and start moving again
}
```

Comment: If you want to know what exactly he is trying to do, look at [his previous question](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/31550/972).

Comment: I did, and I get the gist of it, but I still wasn't confident I understood exactly what was wanted.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Ive uploaded this code and what it seems to do at the moment is turn the motors forward when the value is above 900 but it does not limit that to one second nor does it reverse them when the value falls below 900. I'm gonna work on debugging but if you have any idea why please let me know! Thanks.

Comment: My suspicion is that I incorrectly guessed how to switch the motors off.  My guess was `move(0,0,LEFT);`.  Is that correct?  Also, I just fixed a bug which would have prevented the reverse from working.

Comment: ok ill try it thank you. I suspect an easy way to run the reverse would be: _If EMG goes from above 900 to below 900, run reverse for one second._ Im just not sure what the Arduino code for that is.

Comment: also ive written a function to stop the motors that is simply `stop()`

Comment: Currently, the loop you have provided successfully turns the motors but does not limit them to one second or reverse them when the value goes below 900. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Are you saying that you don't know how to make the motor run in reverse? If that's the case, find that out before getting bogged down with whether the loop is working. (I strongly suspect it is.)

Comment: Also, have you done something to stop the main `loop()` from going round immediately? If not, it'll do just that, meaning it will immediately start turning again (if value >900).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49124/discussion-between-zach-eisner-and-mark-smith).